# How to split one row in two rows (unpivot?)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server I created this test table. And ran the queries.
As you can see rows where `DB_CR_CODE = 'C'` have to be counted twice.

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
       [BOOKING_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
       [TIME_INTERVAL] [int] NOT NULL,
       [DB_CR_CODE] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
       [CHANNEL] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
       [NBR_OF_TXN] [smallint] NOT NULL,
       [AMOUNT] [bigint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0029, 'D', 'ABCD', 1, 100)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0027, 'D', 'ABCD', 1, 200)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0044, 'D', 'ABCD', 1, 300)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0042, 'D', 'ABCD', 1, 400)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0029, 'C', 'ABCD', 1, 500)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0069, 'C', 'ABCD', 1, 600)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0067, 'C', 'XXCD', 1, 700)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0089, 'C', 'ABCD', 1, 800)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0079, 'C', 'XXCD', 1, 900)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES ('2023-04-06', 0084, 'C', 'ABCD', 1, 1000)

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable

-- Main query
-- translate each row one by one without aggregation
-- records with DB_CR_CODE 'C' have to be counted in two different groups
-- meaning that one input record then leads to two output records
SELECT
    BOOKING_DATE, 
    CASE
        WHEN TIME_INTERVAL BETWEEN 0000 AND 0030 THEN 1
        WHEN TIME_INTERVAL BETWEEN 0031 AND 0060 THEN 2
        WHEN TIME_INTERVAL BETWEEN 0061 AND 0090 THEN 3
        ELSE 99 
    END AS interval,
    CASE
        WHEN DB_CR_CODE = 'C' THEN 'Credit'
        WHEN DB_CR_CODE = 'D' THEN 'Debet'        
        ELSE '' 
    END AS PRODUCT_GROUP1,
    CASE 
        WHEN DB_CR_CODE = 'C' AND CHANNEL = 'ABCD' THEN 'Credit_ABCD'  
        ELSE '' 
    END AS PRODUCT_GROUP2,
    NBR_OF_TXN, AMOUNT
FROM 
    dbo.TestTable

-- aggregating the main query above
SELECT
    booking_date, interval, product_group1, product_group2, 
    SUM(nbr_of_txn) AS nbr_txn, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM
    (SELECT
         BOOKING_DATE, 
         CASE
             WHEN TIME_INTERVAL BETWEEN 0000 AND 0030 THEN 1
             WHEN TIME_INTERVAL BETWEEN 0031 AND 0060 THEN 2
             WHEN TIME_INTERVAL BETWEEN 0061 AND 0090 THEN 3
             ELSE 99 
         END AS interval,
         CASE
             WHEN DB_CR_CODE = 'C' THEN 'Credit'
             WHEN DB_CR_CODE = 'D' THEN 'Debet'        
             ELSE '' 
         END AS PRODUCT_GROUP1,
         CASE 
             WHEN DB_CR_CODE = 'C' AND CHANNEL = 'ABCD' THEN 'Credit_ABCD'  
             ELSE '' 
         END AS PRODUCT_GROUP2,
         NBR_OF_TXN, AMOUNT
     FROM
         dbo.TestTable) a
GROUP BY
    booking_date, interval, PRODUCT_GROUP1, PRODUCT_GROUP2
```

The last query returns this as output:

[image: given output]

But I would like it to be like this. So the rows where product_group1 and product_group2 are filled, become two rows. I have been struggling with Unpivot, but can't get it fixed. In the end this will run on a very large table

[image: desired output]

Comment: FYI, it's Deb**i**t not deb*e*t.

Answer (score 0):

try this (aggregate in CTE then UNION ALL):

```
;WITH --first CTE is your data set example
    CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES
                ('2023-04-06', 0029, 'D', 'ABCD', 1, 100),
                ('2023-04-06', 0027, 'D', 'ABCD', 1, 200),
                ('2023-04-06', 0044, 'D', 'ABCD', 1, 300),
                ('2023-04-06', 0042, 'D', 'ABCD', 1, 400),
                ('2023-04-06', 0029, 'C', 'ABCD', 1, 500),
                ('2023-04-06', 0069, 'C', 'ABCD', 1, 600),
                ('2023-04-06', 0067, 'C', 'XXCD', 1, 700),
                ('2023-04-06', 0089, 'C', 'ABCD', 1, 800),
                ('2023-04-06', 0079, 'C', 'XXCD', 1, 900),
                ('2023-04-06', 0084, 'C', 'ABCD', 1, 1000)) AS T([BOOKING_DATE],[TIME_INTERVAL],[DB_CR_CODE],[CHANNEL],[NBR_OF_TXN],[AMOUNT])
    ),
    CTE2 --aggregate data 
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            booking_date, interval, product_group1, product_group2,
            SUM(nbr_of_txn) AS nbr_txn, SUM(amount) AS amount
        FROM
            (SELECT
                BOOKING_DATE,
                CASE
             WHEN TIME_INTERVAL BETWEEN 0000 AND 0030 THEN 1
             WHEN TIME_INTERVAL BETWEEN 0031 AND 0060 THEN 2
             WHEN TIME_INTERVAL BETWEEN 0061 AND 0090 THEN 3
             ELSE 99 
         END AS interval,
                CASE
             WHEN DB_CR_CODE = 'C' THEN 'Credit'
             WHEN DB_CR_CODE = 'D' THEN 'Debit'        
             ELSE '' 
         END AS PRODUCT_GROUP1,
                CASE 
             WHEN DB_CR_CODE = 'C' AND CHANNEL = 'ABCD' THEN 'Credit_ABCD'  
             ELSE '' 
         END AS PRODUCT_GROUP2,
                NBR_OF_TXN, AMOUNT
            FROM
                CTE) a
        GROUP BY booking_date, interval, PRODUCT_GROUP1, PRODUCT_GROUP2
    )

    --UNION from CTE2
    SELECT booking_date, interval, product_group1, nbr_txn, amount
    FROM CTE2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT booking_date, interval, product_group2, nbr_txn, amount
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE product_group2 !=''
```

output result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vasily, your solution, with the aggregate and union, solved my problem . Thnx